# NOT IN select query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to  fetch some values from database except already fetched values,

Here is the query, I want to fetch the values that where not in first fetch,

```
$qry="select value,name,number from test where value=10";
$rslt=mysql_query($qry);
$arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);

$qry2="select value,name,number from test where value NOT IN ('$rslt')";
$rslt2=mysql_query($qry2);

while($arr2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt2))
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arr2);
  echo "<pre>";
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not very descriptive. What were you expecting to get? What you got instead? Any errors/warnings (if so, what do they say)?

Comment: That's not the right approach. Either use pagination (search for that), or invert you query select condition (and beware of NULLs) depending on exactly what you're after.

Comment: Also, `$rslt` is not actually a result, it's a *resource*. You're only getting one result from that (as an associative array) using `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Are you trying to do something like `... WHERE value NOT IN (10)`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not negate the first query to get the second one?

```
select value,name,number from test where value = 10
```

And then:

```
select value,name,number from test where value != 10 or value is null
```

The null check can be ommited if there are no null values in the column

Btw: The error is in here:

```
NOT IN ('$rslt')
```

`NOT IN` expects a comma separated value list such as `NOT IN (1, 5, 6)` or a subquery and your statement does not result in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

`$rslt` is a variable of `resource` type: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

you can't put it into mysql statement and expect it to work. you can change it to `$qry`:
`$qry2="select value,name,number from test where value NOT IN ($qry)";`

Answer (score 0):

You are using $rslt instead of the $arr in your IN statement ... and remember you should first convert the `$arr` into a comma separated list using `implode`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `IN` function needs a literal comma-separated value or a sub-query. You're dropping in an associative array. Try this:

```
$qry="select value,name,number from test where value NOT IN (select value,name,number from test where value=10)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the val to a variable and try below code

```
$val=10;

$qry="select value,name,number from test where value=$val";
$rslt=mysql_query($qry);
$arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);
$qry2="select value,name,number from test where value NOT IN ($val)";
$rslt2=mysql_query($qry2);

while($arr2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt2))
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arr2);
  echo "<pre>";
}
```